# Implicitly map to set in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

After I map through one Set, I have to explicitly cast it back to Set. For example:

```
fun getNewSet(oldSet: Set<String>): Set<String> {
return oldSet
        .map{ getNewStringFromOld(it) }
        .toSet()
}
```

What is the proper way to map through the set without explicitly casting it back to Set?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looking at the library code, the only other way to do this would be to call `mapTo` which takes a destination collection:

```
oldSet.mapTo(HashSet<String>()) { getNewStringFromOld(id) }
```

I'm not sure the default is wrong. The problem is that `map` might be used in a way that results in a list of non-unique values. If there was a special version of `Set.map()` that returned a set, you couldn't use map in that way - any non-unique value would replace the value in the result. I could certainly see the case being made that `map` should always result in a collection that is the same size as the source collection, and if `map` created a `Set`, this wouldn't always be the case.

If you do this often, perhaps just create your own extension function:

```
public inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.mapToSet(transform: (T) -> R): Set<R> {
  return mapTo(HashSet<R>(), transform)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's exactly what I needed. I do use this quite often, so provided extension function comes very handy.

Comment: BTW, the provided explanation is exactly right. Scala maps a set to a set, and it causes bugs if used carelessly

Comment: It's not clear to me whether `map` on a `Set` should implicitly map to a `Set`. But for operations like `filter`, the standard library should implicitly perform a `toSet()`. Does anyone know why they provide a type-preserving `filter` on `Map<K, out V>` but not `Set<T>`? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html#filter-by-predicate

Comment: @breandan Possible explanation: There is an `Iterable.filter(): List`. If they also had `Set.filter(): Set`, it could lead to ambiguous behavior ("surprising" behavior) when a Set is upcast to an Iterable. Sometimes upcasts are implicit so there could be subtle differences in syntax that lead to different functions being called. Since a Map is not an Iterable, this confusion isn't possible for it.